# How to add Currency extension (CAD or USD) to links (e.g.: /currency-usd)?

Tags: magento-1.7

I am trying to add some an Currency ending to links on my Magento store.

For instance, like all Magento store there is an option to switch currency (based on latest conversion) (EURO,CAD,USD,GBP)
Since I have ONE store front and BASE currency is CAD (Canadian Dollars). Customer from United States can view prices in USD currency, but they have to Manually switch currency.

When I send links to my US customers they open the links and see prices in CAD dollars. Because CAD is my BASE currency.

QUESTION:
1. How can I add an extension to links so when US customers open the links they see prices in USD currency ?
For example, it should look something like this:
www.example.com/sport-equipment/soccer ball/**currency=usd**

1. The extension does not have to be static, at least I need a code that I can include manually with each Link so it shows prices in USD currency upon opening.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the storeview switcher for this. Configure your store views to change currencies and add in the URL ?___store=storecode to switch the currencies and the storeviews.

Comment: Storeview creates another store but with USD currency. Essentially I will have to duplicate ALL products that will be with USD dollars. Maybe there is an easier way, just adding some code to URL manually ?

Comment: Duplicate products is not an option and was not what i meant. That is not how a storeview works. You can create a new storeview and define a currency for the storeview and a relation between currencies in Magento to make this without having to duplicate the products.

Comment: I appreciate your help!!! I've never create a another storeview, do you have any instructions how to set it up in my case ?

Comment: Check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7393/difference-between-website-stores-and-store-views and http://sherodesigns.com/magento/magento-tutorial-creating-multiple-store-views-in-magento/ Dont forget to mark the question as resolved too.

Comment: Last thing, do you think there is another way of adding some sort of extension to links (I mostly need this for Email) I email customer links to products and sometimes customers are from USA. Therefore I can manually add extensions to all links I send so once they open it they see price in USD ?

Comment: You might be able to add to the product for each the code I sent you early, after the link. Not sure how and where, open another question and we can see.