# Cannot change locale language : Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

When I open my **.co.uk website**, it says a lot of stuff in Dutch from the pack I installed. I want my **German** website to be **German**, **Dutch** to be **Dutch** and **English** to be **English**.

> Why it is not working?
>
> How can I fix this?

I don't know from where to start. Is the switch able to be made in the database?

I tried to switch to developer mode, but than the system doesn't give a CSS to the backend, so I cannot get to the option.

**My website:**

> https://www.thefixedgearshop.co.uk

The storeviews:
[image: Storeviews]

Not switchable

[image: Locale not switchable]

Answer (score 14):

You do not need to setup a "Website" instead of a "Store View". Store Views are used specifically for different languages if need.

Starting in magento 2.2.X you need to change the store to Developer Mode in order to update the Locale option.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

After applying the developer mode and the locales are deployed, revert back to Production mode

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Look at this GitHub issue for more details: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10377

Answer (score 6):

You can actually just delete the "Disabled" attribute in the dom, make the change and save it. This should update the locale to what you specify.

Don't need to change modes.

Comment: Genius haha seems to work

Comment: This was perfect

Answer (score 0):

In your locale options, **untick** the "Use Website" and select your locale option.

Comment: That is not possible. I cannot untick it cause its locked.

Comment: Ahh, if you want to have a different locale, you need to create a new website, not a store view.

Comment: So I need to switch my current storeview to a website, not a storeview? Does that infect the current information on the site or? Don't I already have that in website?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7393/difference-between-website-stores-and-store-views

Comment: I checked it but if I look at my current set-up than that is correct? The storeviews I created are to show a store in a different language. The Locale says Dutch (Netherlands) for all of the languages. I cannot edit this?

Comment: Are you using an admin account with no restrictions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74634/discussion-between-axel-dekker-and-bare-feet).

Comment: In Production mode, you cannot change locale for website or store, Instead you can do remove disabled validation on Use Website checkbox and change the dropdown value and save it. That will work.

Answer (score 0):

No need to creat anew store view, just switch to developer mode, change it and switch back to production

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer --skip-compilation
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution at the moment seems to be the one at https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10377#issuecomment-484470446