# Multi Website, Store and Store view in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

How to check whether our module is compatiable for multi website, multi store and multi store views?

Comment: you can check in system.xml inside define in_website,in_store,in_store view.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the features and scope included in your module. If your module has simple features which are same on all the websites, locales and languages then there is no need to make it compatible with each of it.

If your module contains features which may be different on different websites, locales and languages then you have to make it compatible as per your requirements.

If you want to actually check if your module is compatible with multiple websites, stores and store views then you will require to create multiple website with multiple stores and store views and then check your module with each instance.

You can find more details on [Websites, Stores and Store Views](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/7399/2443) in Magento